# Open new msys terminal and run commands

Tags: shell, mingw, msys

I am trying to create a shell script that opens three new msys terminals and let each run a specific set of commands or let each run shell files containing the commands.

What I am trying to do is to have the following:

```
somepath/startAll.sh  
somepath/a/first.sh  
somepath/b/second.sh  
somepath/c/third.
```

Then be able to run the `startAll.sh` script which starts three new msys terminals which runs the `first.sh`, `second.sh` and `third.sh` scripts, respectively.

I am working on Windows7 and tried a lot of things, but nothing works..

I am really stuck on this one, my shell scripting skills are not that evolved yet, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

On another note: I saw someone comment on another similar question that msys and mingw[32] is not the same thing. Although when installing msys/mingw a autogenerated desktop shortcut was called msys was created, and it starts a mingw32 terminal? I apologize in advance if I mix the two.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the only bash in your command prompt is the msys one,  you can go with:

```
start bash
start bash
start bash
```

then just execute it with "bash scriptfile.sh".  If you have other bash executables, just use an absolute path.  Each bash can have a different command after it to run, that could be a script file.

Edit: I just double checked this, and apparently the windows close as soon as they are done when you include a command.  Not sure that is an acceptable solution for you, or how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out once I get home tonight!